# Selenium python , element could not be scrolled into view

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqcBJ.png)

Im working with selenium;
This is my code:

```
element = wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable(e.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'a')))
            
element.click()
```

and I get this error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <a href=""> could not be scrolled into view
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you also show your rendered html?

Comment: I have add a picture of html code

Comment: Can you share a link to that page? Not a picture, it is useless.

Comment: are you sure there is only one `a` element in you result? It could be that there are more than one elements found

Comment: That was problem. Thank you so much